# Document query selector for a controller in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I have a controller named like this :

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main" class="containerWrap">
```

I tried this for selecting my controller for further functioning :-

```
var a = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=MainController as main]');
var b = angular.element(chatElement).scope();
```

It gives an error :-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[ng-controller=MainController as main]' is not a valid selector.
```

I tried for just MainController as well :-

That gives :-

```
a=null
b=undefined
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add quotes around "MainController as main".

Comment: Thanks. Earlier I did not have main as instance.Works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="MainController as main"]');
```